# Should codes be written before super.initState(); or after in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Should the code that is being written to `initState()` function be written before `super.initState();` or after?

Which one is proper:

```
  @override
    // code here
    super.initState();
  }
```

or

```
  @override
    super.initState();
    // code here
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

both will work.

But if you see from any dependencies or official docs flutter, write your code in `initSate()` after `super.initState();`

```
@overrride
initState(){
  super.initState()
  //your code
}
```

reference to this [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/initState.html)

the opposite for `dispose()`, write your code before super.dispose();

```
@overrride
dispose(){
  //your code
  super.dispose()
}
```

reference to [dispose](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/dispose.html)

When I see @Kahoo answer, I check it by cmd + click at super.dispose and super.initstate, I found this for dispose

```
  /// If you override this, make sure to end your method with a call to
  /// super.dispose().
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [deactivate], which is called prior to [dispose].
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void dispose() {
    assert(_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.ready);
    assert(() {
      _debugLifecycleState = _StateLifecycle.defunct;
      return true;
    }());
  }
```

Comment: Does this mean that if we write code after super.dispose() in dispose() method, then it will not be executed ??  In android studio, generated code looks as follows. TODO comment is before super.initState()                     
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

Comment: as I say, both will work. but sometimes, before execute a function, it need to finish the render for the first time or we have to wait until first render completed with postframe, maybe, i not so understand about that. It's okay to place it before super.initstate() or see @Kahou answer. But for the comment, if you see, all the overriden method place TODO comment at the same position. maybe I'm wrong too

Answer (score 3):

abstract class State :

```
  /// If you override this, make sure your method starts with a call to
  /// super.initState().
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState() {
    assert(_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created);
  }
```